# How to make a method which will start at a certain time of the system?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm working on an application which simulates a football game. So, I have football matches which will start at a certain time.

For example, a match could take place at 25 May, 20:00 o' clock. How can I tell to Spring to start the method which simulates the match?

I'am using Spring MVC and Apache Tomcat. (+ Spring Data JPA and Hibernate). Who can tell me some ideas and advices?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about scheduling a cURL command to run with something like cron?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Spring's `@Scheduled` annotation for scheduling jobs
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-scheduled

```
@Scheduled(cron="0 0 20 25 MAY *")
public void doSomething() {
    // something that should execute on weekdays only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write `cron` which is totally separate from the java code which you have. The `cron` job can be scheduled to run at a particular time, and it is in this job that you will have to start the method that simulates the match.